# Card on file with Square In person payments

Tags: square-connect

I have gone through the in person payments with Square and read the save card on file in Square documentation. I wonder if there is any way to save Card on file while in person payments? or may be i am missing something in documentation?

Because while in person payments, currently we are not saving customer's any information but the `server_transaction_id`. If we want to save Card on file, do we need to save customer's other information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not with the APIs at this time, but by using the built-in capabilities of Square Point of Sale. see: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5770-use-card-on-file-with-the-square-point-of-sale-app